# Problem while trying to add a custom layer with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, layer

I'm trying to add impulse noise between two parts of my model(encoder and decoder), so I wrote a custom layer just to add noise. Here's my progress so far:

```
class impulse_noise(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(impulse_noise, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
       self.kernel = self.add_weight(name = 'kernel',
          shape = (input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
          initializer = 'normal', trainable = True)
       super(impulse_noise, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, input_data):
        signal_power = np.mean(abs(input_data ** 2))
        sigma2 = signal_power * 10 ** (-7 / 10)
        sigma3 = 0.02
        Gaussian = np.random.randn(*input_data.shape) + 1j * np.random.randn(*input_data.shape)
        power1 = np.zeros([*input_data.shape])
        power2 = np.zeros([*input_data.shape])
        for test_row_element in range(*input_data.shape):
            k = np.random.rand()
            if k > prob:
                power1[test_row_element] = np.sqrt(sigma2 / 2)
                power2[test_row_element] = np.sqrt(sigma2 / 2)
            if k <= prob:
                power1[test_row_element] = np.sqrt(sigma3 / 2)
                power2[test_row_element] = np.sqrt(sigma3 / 2)
        noise1 = np.multiply(power1, Gaussian.real)
        noise2 = np.multiply(power2, Gaussian.imag)
        noise_BG = np.zeros([*input_data.shape]).astype(complex)
        noise_BG.real = noise1
        noise_BG.imag = noise2
        noise_symbol = noise_BG + input_data  # NoiseSymbol
        noise_symbol_real = noise_symbol.real
        noise_symbol_image = noise_symbol.imag
        noise_symbol = []
        for j in range(0, len(input_data)):
            final_signal.append((np.sqrt((noise_symbol_image[j] ** 2) + (noise_symbol_real[j] ** 2))))
        return final_signal

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape): return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

Here's my model:

```
input_signal = Input(shape=(M,))
encoded = Dense(M, activation='relu')(input_signal)
encoded1 = Dense(n_channel, activation='linear')(encoded)
encoded2 = BatchNormalization()(encoded1)

EbNo_train = 5.01187#coverted 7 db of EbNo
#encoded3 = GaussianNoise(np.sqrt(1/(2*R*EbNo_train)))(encoded2)
encoded3 = impulse_noise(7)(encoded2)
decoded = Dense(M, activation='relu')(encoded3)
decoded1 = Dense(M, activation='softmax')(decoded)

autoencoder = Model(input_signal, decoded1)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(data, data,
                epochs=17,
                batch_size=300,
                validation_data=(val_data, val_data))
```

But it keep show me this error

```
 File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/autoencoder_7_4_symbol.py", line 85, in <module>
    encoded3 = impulse_noise(7)(encoded2)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 489, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/autoencoder_7_4_symbol.py", line 28, in call
    signal_power = np.mean(abs(input_data ** 2))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in mean
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3373, in mean
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 144, in _mean
    arr = asanyarray(a)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 136, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 736, in __array__
    " array.".format(self.name))
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (impulse_noise_1/Abs:0) to a numpy array.
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. I looked up for convert Tensor to numpy by using .numpy(), but it seems like the "symbolic Tensor" can't do this.
My another idea is to read the output from encoded2 and just add noise to it's value, then send the result into next layer. Is this realizable with keras?

Comment: Two observations: 1) In custom keras layer code, you need to use tensorflow operations.  Everything in your call code has an equivalent to your numpy function in the TensorFlow API.  If you do not do this, no gradients will flow back to your encoder and it won't update/improve. 2) try to get rid of your for loop and process it in a vectorized way and without index assignment to a zero buffer.  One way is to generate a vector of random numbers up front  and use `tf.where` to create the conditionally noised array

Comment: Please look into Tensorflow's math/utility functions to replace the numpy ones you are using; they are compatible with symbolic tensors.

Comment: Hi! Could you also try again by disabling eager execution or downgrading numpy 
version  1.19.5 .    Ref- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/52380